# Django - MS Active Directory authentification using django-auth-ldap

Tags: django, active-directory, ldap3, django-auth-ldap

I almost broke my mind trying to adjust my test django project to connect with my Active Directory.
The goal is to create a simple login page that will check credentials with AD users data.
AD located on the same machine as Django.
AD users involved into process: admin, bind
AD groups involved: django-admins
AD has a default structure, with default Users folder where I created my users and a group.

My settings.py file is below

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://192.168.149.10"
AUTH_LDAP_AUTHORIZE_ALL_USERS = True
AUTH_LDAP_PERMIT_EMPTY_PASSWORD = True
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "CN=bind,CN=Users,DC=ATK,DC=BIZ"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "Hahalala90!"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
            "dc=ATK,dc=BIZ", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s"
            )


AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
    "dc=ATK,dc=BIZ",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    "(objectCategory=Group)",
)
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType(name_attr="cn")

AUTH_LDAP_START_TLS = True

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail",
}

AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active": "cn=active,CN=django-admins,CN=Users,DC=ATK,DC=BIZ",
    "is_staff": "cn=staff,cn=django-admins,cn=Users,dc=ATK,dc=BIZ",
    "is_superuser": "cn=superuser,cn=django-admins,cn=Users,dc=ATK,dc=BIZ",
}

AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_GROUPS = True


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

DRAL_CHECK_DOMAIN = False
```

I followed the official documentation of django-auth-ldap and many others sources.
And when I try to login into django-admin panel I receive `Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.`.
Moreover, I tried to login through my login page and received response 200 with
`data:{success: false, error: 'Invalid username or password'}`

So obviously it doesn't recognize my credentials.

Please, show me the direction, I tried almost everything in these 3 weeks.

P.S. Ldap is running, the only thing that worked is a ldap3 library.

Tried this:
https://techexpert.tips/django/django-ldap-authentication-active-directory/
Tried this:
https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Tried:
ldap3
django-auth-ldap3
django-auth-ldap3-ad
Tried to use django remoteAuth
The only thing that gave me a hope is ldap3, through which I received the list of all members of django-admins AD group.